# Joining table data with expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, sql, csv, attribute-joins

I use QGIS 3.4 as a beginner.

I have a vector layer `'Address'` with the fields:

```
"Id"(int)
"postalcode" (str)
"straatname"(str)
"housenr"(int)
```

and a CSV-file with the fields

```
"section" (int)
"postalcode" (str)
"housenr_low" (int)
"housenr_high" (int)
```

I want to add the field `"section"` from the CSV -ile to the `'Address'` layer `where Address.postalcode = CSV.postcalcode and Address.housenr >= CSV.housenr_low and Address.housenr <= CSV.housenr_high`.

I tried *"join with the attribute table"* and *"Join attributes by field value"* without success.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround by using `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` to create first a link tabel with only key fields and in a second step *"Join attributes by field value"*.

But because my case is so common, there must be a beter solution out of the box with QGIS. So I hope an experienced GIS expert tell us how to do this.

Comment: It is possible to do it in one step but for performance reasons I choose the extra step.
The tip for using a Virtual Layer came from editor Taras, my thanks to him.